# SSRS page break on large data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, break, row-number

I have a table that get a data from dataset. The table is larger then a one page. When I export to PDF the table cut in the middle and without a borders.
I tried to use rectangle and it's not working for me. I tried to use in expression like this "=ROWNUMBER(Nothing)/50" and it's  not working too.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: can you show what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps :
1. create parent group on your tablix.

2. Once you click on Parent Group, it will open a Tablix Group window. In the Group By expression, enter =CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/25) where 25 is the number of records to be displayed per page.
3. you can go to the created group properties for more options to try out.